# Is XMLHttpRequest secure over HTTPS?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, https, xmlhttprequest

I am developing a PHP/JS web application in which I make heavy use of the `XMLHttpRequest` object (for page updates / AJAX, etc.). Among many other areas, I use this in my user management code (login, signup, etc.). Specifically, I use it to send passwords in plain text through XMLHttpRequests (to then be hashed by the server and stored safely away in the database). To illustrate with a minimal example, the process looks something like this:

```js
// Define the HTTP request parameters
var username = "my_username";
var password = "my_super_secure_password";
var addr = "/my_app/check_login";
var post = "ACTION=CREATE_USER&USERNAME=" + username + "&PASSWORD=" + password;

// Create the XMLHttpRequest object
xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function ()
{
     // AJAX stuff goes here!
}
xhttp.open("POST", addr, true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

// And away it goes!
xhttp.send(post);
```

Obviously, on my localhost setup (HTTP only with MAMP, no security), this works wonders. However, I am concerned about uploading this to my host server (HTTPS / SSL, etc.) and whether it will a) be successful and, most importantly, b) be secure.

I don't know whether the `XMLHttpRequest` object would automatically adjust to the same protocol the page is using - if not, sending the user's passwords through this would obviously pose a security risk. I would be very grateful if someone more competent than me could let me know - and, if this is in fact insecure, inform me of any alternative ways to use AJAX more securely.

Thanks!

Comment: If your XHR is using your HTTPS URL, then yes, it's secure. Also you might want to look into using the `fetch()` API, as it's significantly easier to use. Countless thousands, if not millions, of existing web applications use secure ajax today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, sending the requests over HTTPS with `XMLHttpRequest` is as secure as sending them over HTTPS with `fetch` or normal form submission.

> I don't know whether the `XMLHttpRequest` object would automatically adjust to the same protocol the page is using

That depends on the URL you are passing to the `open()` method, i.e. your `addr`. If it is a [relative URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_URL), then yes. If it is an absolute URL, you could send a HTTP request even from a page loaded over HTTPS - which is a bad idea, and you can guard against this happening accidentally (or even maliciously) with a [content security policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Security_Policy) to prevent [mixed content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content).